# SQL Server IDE/Manager

Tags: sql-server

Is there any third party IDE/manager available for Microsft SQL Server Like Navicat or EMS SQL Manager which fast and good.

I use EMS Manager but it is slow even on local system.

Thanks

Comment: Toad for SQL Server: http://www.toadsoft.com/toadsqlserver/toad_sqlserver.htm

Comment: Ems works perfect with Firebird SQL. MSSQL is slow

Comment: I know that but if you ever use navicat which is for mysql and orcale there is no comparison between studio and it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) if you don't want to use SQL Server tools

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one from Microsoft - SQL Server Management Studio. There is a [free edition](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) (Express) too. It is not slow in my experience.

Comment: I know that but if you ever use navicat which is for mysql and orcale there is no comparison between studio and it

Comment: No comparison? I am sure you can list some of the things that you are missing... perhaps that will also help direct people to give you an answer better suited to your needs.